# Concatenate a Spark structured streaming dataframe with a static dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I've got a Spark structured streaming job that reads CSV files, runs some calculations and outputs a text file for use in a model downstream. The output is a single column made up from the original columns that have been concatenated (separated by a space). E.g:

```
1556951121 7.19 26.6 36.144 14.7402 1
1556951122 7.59 27.1 37.697 14.7402 1
1556951123 8.01 27.7 39.328 14.7403 0
etc.
```

The downstream model requires some extra header information at the top of the file. It needs the filename on the first line and the number of columns on the second line. E.g:

```
filename
6
1556951121 7.19 26.6 36.144 14.7402 1
1556951122 7.59 27.1 37.697 14.7402 1
1556951123 8.01 27.7 39.328 14.7403 0
etc.
```

Can this be done in Spark? I created the header information as a separate dataframe:

```
header = [('filename',), ('6',)]
rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(header)
headerDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=StructType([StructField('values', StringType(), False)]))
```

I've tried a `union` but a union between a streaming and static dataframe is not supported.

I also looked at `join` but I don't think that is going to give me what I need as this will add an extra column.

For info, this is the output query:

```
df.coalesce(1)\
  .writeStream\
  .outputMode("append")\
  .format("text")\
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)\
  .option("path", path)\
  .start()\
  .awaitTermination()
```

and this is the input source:

```
df = sparkSession.readStream\
                 .option("header", "true")\
                 .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)\
                 .schema(schema)\
                 .csv(input_path)
```

The input CSVs just consist of a timestamp and some sensor values. E.g:

```
Timestamp,Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3,Sensor4,Sensor5
1556951121,7.19,26.6,36.144,14.7402,True
1556951122,7.59,27.1,37.697,14.7402,True
1556951123,8.01,27.7,39.328,14.7403,False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used the `foreachBatch` sink as this gives you a static dataframe which you can then join/union to other dataframes:

```
df.coalesce(1).writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

And the foreach batch function:

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
     complete_df = headerDF.union(df)
     complete_df.coalesce(1).write.text(os.path.join(output_path, str(epoch_id)))
```